# Corona SDK - repeated notifications

Tags: lua, notifications, coronasdk

I have some code in Corona that triggers a notification 60 seconds after the app was started. It looks like this:

```
local notifications = require( "plugin.notifications" )
-- Set up notification options
local notificationOptions = {
    alert = "Wake up!",
    badge = 2,
    sound = "alarm.caf",
    custom = { foo = "bar" }
}
local notification1 = notifications.scheduleNotification( 60, notificationOptions )
```

I can't, however, find how to make this periodic. For example, once a minute, once every hour, once a day at a particular time, etc.

Any ideas how to do that?

Thanks.

Regards,
Serban

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to run this in a loop, something like this (for one hour every minute):

```
   local notificationTable = []    
   for i=1,60 do
     local time = 60*i
     local handle = notifications.scheduleNotification( time, notificationOptions )
     notificationTable[time] = handle 
   end
```

Note: the code is not tested and for the array there might be other, better ways of doing it, but this should give you an idea. 
For the particular time you will need to use a UTC time instead of the amount of seconds from now.

> A table indicating the Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) at which to deliver the notification. This table should contain the same properties as returned by os.date( "!*t" ). Note that a common pitfall is to pass "*t" instead of "!*t" which results in a time given in your current time zone instead of a UTC time.

https://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/plugin/notifications/scheduleNotification.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, this helps. I was hoping not to have to loop, because then it is more difficult to cancel specific notifications.

Comment: you could create a table that holds the handles for all of the notifications. You also could ad key value pairs where the key is the time and the value is the handle, so you can cancel the notification by its time... I will update my answer to reflect that.

Comment: good idea. thanks. that's what i wanted - cancel individual notifications, not all of them.